# Is this question on book recommendations allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions, resource-recommendation

I would like to ask the following question, and would like to know if it is allowed:

> What are the books similar to the books by David Griffiths, but in the following areas:
>   Classical Mechanics, Statistical Mechanics, Mathematical Methods, Solid State, Atomic and Molecular Physics, Nuclear and Particle Physics?
>
> I like the style of Griffiths, and would like to learn the basics of every area with the least pain possible.

Just wondering if it is appropriate for physics.SE or if I should post this in physics forums.

Comment: To help get you on your way: Griffiths also has a particle physics book, and Daniel Schroeder's book on thermodynamics and statistical mechanics is in a similar style.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking out Schroeder and Griffiths. Although the subject that is giving me most trouble is Classical Mechanics, because I have to cover the same topics as Goldstein has but I find his book a little too advanced. What I need is a commentary on Goldstein's book!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, too specific for this site. As the answer to [the recommendation question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) says,

> It should be of the form "What are good books to learn/study [subject] at [level]?"

Your question is not of that form.

What you could do, though, is check the book recommendation questions for the subjects you're asking about and see if anyone has mentioned about anything being in a similar style to Griffiths.